Anime movie with a sick guy who was able to kill vampires by glowing and emitting beams of light
So it is from somewhere in between the late 90s and early 00s.
There was a gang that killed vampires (a vampire-killing gang?). They wore armor somewhat similar to Warhammer and Warcraft at the same time and their weapons consisted of hammers, swords and guns. Also, there was a machine gun on top of their fully armored van, I think.
One scene that I really remembered involved a guy with some health condition from which he always lay in bed surrounded by medical devices (maybe their van was an ambulance?). Although he was pitied and everybody felt bad about him once, in a very bad situation, he helped his friends with vampires.
They were pursuing a bunch of vampires in the car chase. The vampires though were tough and did some madness that the protagonist group couldn't help themselves with.
At some point, the sick guy stood up at the top of the car and started glowing and emitting light beams. One vampire opened his jacket under which presumably was a space of everything absorbing endless. The sick guy's beams pierced through the vampire and the vampire wasn't happy about it.
This is mostly all that I can remember. To help with recognition I like to make an illustration of the scene (I'm not an artist):

I watched it when I was around six, and still after 20 years I sometimes remember it.

+1 for the illustration - that is a lost art!

+1 for the illustration from me too. I feel like I could use the same illustration to ask about a movie where a guy has to get from one roof to another so he takes apart a bunch of Bic pens, glues the little springs to his torso, then bellyflops off his roof and bounces onto the next one. Knowing this site, someone will find such a movie in about 5 minutes.

Is this maybe the movie Vampire Hunter D: Bloodlust? There are a band of sibling vamp hunters and one is sickly and in a hospital bed, named Grove. He unleashes his light beams and dies soon after.
Groveck Marcus in action




For anyone who's into violent anime with mature themes, I highly recommend checking more of Madhouse, Inc.'s output, especially Wicked City (1987) and Ninja Scroll (1993).

What a priceless movie! Zero wonder I remembered this scene for so long time. Sure this is different level of what I expected. I thought it would be some low budget nonsense. Thak you sandworm!
